# Is it safe to use a win32 dll in an mfc application?

Tags: c++, winapi, mfc

I have a win32 DLL that includes `Windows.h` and makes use of the windows API. I want to load this DLL into an application that uses MFC.

Will this cause any memory leaks or strange behavior? or is it safe?

Comment: I don't understand *"I have a win32 DLL that includes `Windows.h`"*. A .dll certainly doesn't include a header file.

Comment: you can't include "Windows.h" and "afxwin.h" in the same binary, so I am asking if using a dll+exe using those two different APIs will cause any problems.

Comment: I have read that linking different versions of the CRT between an app and a DLL can cause problems, so I thought I would ask if the same is also true for using different version of the windows api.

Comment: There's a bit of confusion here: MFC is not a different API. It is a wrapper implemented on top of the Windows API. There is no incompatibility between MFC and the Windows API. MFC however includes `windows.h` and barfs if you include `windows.h` prior to including `afxwin.h`. This is to prevent **source code** incompatibilities (MFC has quite a bit conditional code). If you want to use the Windows API from MFC either directly or through a regular .dll there is no problem at all.

Comment: @albundy: You can use `<windows.h>` and `<afxwin.h>` in the same binary, just not in the same Translation unit (.cpp and its headers).

Comment: @MSalters That's not correct. `<afxwin.h>` eventually includes `<windows.h>`, so if you `#include <afxwin.h>` you do not even have a choice, `<windows.h>` will be included in the same translation unit. The restriction is on the order: you cannot `#include <windows.h>` **prior** to `<afxwin.h>`. You can `#include <windows.h>` as many times as you wish **after** `<afxwin.h>` has been included.

Comment: @IInspectable: entirely true, but my response was more about the scope of the rule (single TU) than the exact details.

Comment: @MSalters With respect to scope it does make a lot more sense. I didn't look at it from that perspective, which probably explains my response to your statement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MFC is implemented on top of the Windows API. An MFC application can call into the Windows API without any restrictions. It is, however, not possible (nor required) to `#include <windows.h>` prior to including `afxwin.h`. If you do, `afxv_w32.h` will error out with the following message:

> WINDOWS.H already included.  MFC apps must not `#include <windows.h>`

The reason behind this is not a compatibility issue. It is due to the fact, that MFC has to set up several preprocessor symbols to control certain aspects of the compilation process. Those symbols must be defined prior to including `windows.h` (which `afxv_w32.h` eventually does include).

Likewise, there are no problems associated with linking against a .dll that is implemented using the Windows API. In fact, a default MFC application already links against a number of Windows API libraries, like `kernel32.dll` and `user32.dll`. If the header file declaring the .dll exports includes `windows.h` you need to make sure that it is included after `afxwin.h`. Otherwise the preprocessor will error out with the message quoted above.